# jQuery slide delay for Joomla yt megamenu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working Joomla extension (YT Mega menu). I want to make some updates to the existing code.

Here is the code for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```
        li.addEvent('mouseenter', function (e) {
        //if (objectReference.hasOpenning) return;
        log('enter parent of ' + (ul ? ul.id : 'li has not child'));
        li.addClass('hover');
        if (ulexists) {
            objectReference.showChild(ul);
        }
    });
    li.addEvent('mouseleave', function (e) {
        log('leave parent of ' + (ul ? ul.id : 'li has not child'));
        li.removeClass('hover');
        if (ulexists) {
            if (ul.pinned) return false;
            objectReference.hideChild(ul);
        }
    });
```

On `mouseleave` i want a delay before hiding the `ul`.
is there any way to do this?

Please help. I am a beginner and confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
objectReference.hideChild(ul);
```

To

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    objectReference.hideChild(ul); 
},time);
```

time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

On `mouseleave` add a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) like following

```
li.addEvent('mouseleave', function (e) {
    setTimeout(functio(){
        log('leave parent of ' + (ul ? ul.id : 'li has not child'));
        li.removeClass('hover');
        if (ulexists) {
         if (ul.pinned) return false;
         objectReference.hideChild(ul);
       }
   },TIME); 
});
```

Where `TIME` is the amount of time in `milliseconds` you want it to wait before hiding.